# How to pass data to an array that is inside data function from mounted function in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vue-directives, vuejs3

I am trying to pass data to the receieved array which is inside data function here i am fetching data from firebase and want to display in vue table but it is showing error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'receieved' of undefined
can anyone help me how to do this?
Thanks in advance

```html
TypeError: Cannot set property 'receieved' of undefined
    at eval (Main.vue?48a8:78)
    at eval (index.cjs.js?8c4d:4337)
    at LLRBNode.inorderTraversal (index.cjs.js?8c4d:2689)
    at LLRBNode.inorderTraversal (index.cjs.js?8c4d:2688)
    at SortedMap.inorderTraversal (index.cjs.js?8c4d:3139)
    at ChildrenNode.forEachChild (index.cjs.js?8c4d:3748)
    at DataSnapshot.forEach (index.cjs.js?8c4d:4336)
    at eval (Main.vue?48a8:74)
    at eval (index.cjs.js?8c4d:4551)
    at exceptionGuard (index.cjs.js?8c4d:700)
```

```js
<script>
import firebase from 'firebase';
export default {
    data(){
      return{
          receieved: [],
      }
    },
    name: 'Main',
      mounted(){ 
        var detailRequestRef = firebase.database().ref("nokia_track/current_location");
        detailRequestRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
          //Retrieve Request Data
          var detailRequestData = child.val();
          console.log(detailRequestData);
          this.receieved = detailRequestData
          console.log(receieved);
         });
     });
  }
}

</script>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// without arrow function
mounted() { 
  const that = this;
  var detailRequestRef = firebase.database().ref("nokia_track/current_location");
  detailRequestRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    var detailRequestData = child.val();
    that.receieved.push = detailRequestData;
  });
});


// with arrow function
mounted() { 
  var detailRequestRef = firebase.database().ref("nokia_track/current_location");
  detailRequestRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    var detailRequestData = child.val();
    this.receieved.push = detailRequestData
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will probably work and not error out

```
<script>
import firebase from 'firebase';
export default {
    data(){
      return{
          receieved: [],
      }
    },
    name: 'Main',
      mounted(){ 
        var detailRequestRef = firebase.database().ref("nokia_track/current_location");
        detailRequestRef.on('value',(snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
          //Retrieve Request Data
          var detailRequestData = child.val();
          console.log(detailRequestData);
          this.receieved = detailRequestData
          console.log(this.receieved);
         });
     });
  }
}

</script>
```

But I think what you looking for is:

```
<script>
import firebase from 'firebase';
export default {
    data(){
      return{
          receieved: [],
      }
    },
    name: 'Main',
      mounted(){ 
        var detailRequestRef = firebase.database().ref("nokia_track/current_location");
        detailRequestRef.on('value',(snapshot)=>{
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
          //Retrieve Request Data
          var detailRequestData = child.val();
          console.log(detailRequestData);
          this.receieved.push(detailRequestData)

         });
         console.log(this.receieved);
     });
  }
}

</script>
```

1. When you inside a function you can't accsess the scope of the app, unless you use arrow function syntax.
2. You want to add the data when you loop over and add to the array and output after you have all the data in the array

Comment: try now. I updated the console log to this.receieved

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function instead of the `forEach` iterator function. Because `this` context is not the vue component.

```
detailRequestRef.on('value',(snapshot)=>{//arrow function
        snapshot.forEach((child)=>{//arrow function
          //Retrieve Request Data
          var detailRequestData = child.val();
          console.log(detailRequestData);
          this.receieved.push(detailRequestData)

         });
         console.log(receieved);
     });
```

or

```
var self = this;//set function context to a var.
detailRequestRef.on('value',(snapshot)=>{
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
          //Retrieve Request Data
          var detailRequestData = child.val();
          console.log(detailRequestData);
          self.receieved.push(detailRequestData)//use it

         });
         console.log(receieved);
     });
```